# How to determine change in effect over time?

Tags: repeated-measures

I would like to determine if the effect of binary variable (like gender) on a continuous variable (like a reaction time in ms) can change overtime (between T1 and T2). I have over 100 subjects.

What statistical test could help be answer this question ?

Thank you very much,

Antoine

Comment: How many times did you measure the reaction time from the same subject? Just at T1 and T2?

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. 
yes two measures , one at T1 the other at T2.

Comment: This is a classic 2 by 2 factorial ANOVA with a within groups factor (time) and a between groups factor (gender). This will provide you with two main effects (one for each factor) and an interaction. The interaction tests whether the change over time differences between genders (i.e., the effect you are interested in).

Comment: Thank you dbwilson, I understand your answer, but the interaction could also mean that time affected more male than women (or the otherway around). But is there a way to determine only the effect of sex at two time points and compare those effects ?

Answer (score 1):

Fit a mixed linear model:

$$Y_{ij}=\alpha +\beta_1X_{1ij} +\beta_2X_{2ij} + \beta_3 X_{1ij}X_{2ij} + \gamma_i +\epsilon_{ij}$$
where $i$ for subject, $j$ for time, $X_{1ij}$ is for gender, and $X_{2ij}$ for time. $\gamma_{i}$ is random subject specific intercept.

If the interaction term is not significant, then the effect of gender does not change over this two time points. If it is significant, the effect of gender is not the same over the two time points, and you can figure out the effects of gender on each time point separately.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm going to try that. But I wonder, if the interaction is significant, it means that the effect of gender is different between the two times points, but could that also mean that the effect of time is different in genders?

Comment: "the effect of gender is different between the two times points" = "the effect of time is different in genders".

Comment: hmm... that is what I thought... isn't there a way to determine the effect of gender at T0 (let's call it A) and then at T1 (let's call it B) and then to compare A and B ?

Comment: Suppose the interaction is significant. Then A and B depend on the code (or dummy). Suppose 0 for male, 1 for female; 0 for time T1, 2 for time t2. Then A (female vs male) = $\beta_1$, B=$\beta_1+\beta_3$. For comparing A and B, just see $\beta_3$.

Comment: They are the same, $\beta_3$.